# A quick way of showing $4$ is an associate to $(1+i)^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is stated in my notes as if its obvious, but I cant immediately see it.

I know that the norm of $1+i$ is 2 and that $1+i$ is irreducible in the Guassian Integers

Comment: $i(1+i)=i-1=-(1-i)=-\overline{(1+i)}$

Comment: Expand $(1+i)^4$ (either using Newton binomial or by squaring it twice).

Comment: Well, it's obvious that the reader can do the math her/himself and see if it is an associate.  (1+i)^2 = 2i so s (1+i)^4 = -4 which is "obviously" an associate of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $(1+i)^2=2i$ so that $(1+i)^4=(2i)^2=-4$. Now $\pm 1, \pm i$ is a unit in the ring of Gaussian integers, so that $(1+i)^4$ and $4$ are associate. Note that we have also shown that $(1+i)^2$ and $2$ are associate, and that $2$ is not irreducible.

Comment: It happens.$$$$